# Serial terminal emulator for Ubuntu ( Zorin ) - PuTTY config window is too big for screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, putty

I've installed Zorin on an old netbook with the aim of using it as a serial terminal to read and store data from an Arduino (eg Nano).
I cant use PuTTY because it looks like this - the bottom part of the config window
(shown hatched) is below the taskbar and I cant move it up to launch the terminal.

[image: image of putty config window]

Is there a way to reduce the size of the config window - as I dont need all the options?  Or is there another SIMPLE serial terminal emulator thqat will let me interrface to an Arduino via the USB port?

Comment: Related: [How to connect to a serial port as simple as using SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22545/108618).

Comment: "*Or is there another SIMPLE serial terminal emulator ...?*" -- Try **minicom** from the shell in a terminal window. IOW it's a text-based program (that conforms to the terminal window it is in) rather than a GUI app.

Answer (score 0):

I installed CuteCom, and after some issues it now works well.

Connecting to arduino: using CuteCom
“permission denied” need to allow user access to ttyUSB0 port.

You need to add your user to two groups to have access to the usb ports. These groups are dialout and tty:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty $USER
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

If all else fails you need to set the permission for the port each time, like this: sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0